# Creating and sending raw data packets in C/C++

Tags: c++, c, sockets, protocols, packets

I know how my packet looks like. It has `6` header fields (1 byte each, each header has 8 fields) and then it has the payload (data).

I would like to build a raw packet in C or C++ (it should look the same I think).

Here's what I think I should do:

```
    unsigned char packet[11];

    packet[0] = (0x81); // first header with 8 fields
    packet[1] = (0x8c); // second header with 8 fields
    packet[2] = (0xfe);
    packet[3] = (0x84);
    packet[4] = (0x1d);
    packet[5] = (0x79);
    packet[6] = (0x96); // payload, the 'h' letter, masked
    packet[7] = (0xe1); // 'e'
    packet[8] = (0x71); // 'l'
    packet[9] = (0x15); // 'l'
    packet[10] = (0x91);// 'o'
```

Where, for instance, `0x81` is the first byte (I simply converted every field (bit) of my first header to hex).

And then, simply, I want to send it to server: `send(sockfd, packet, sizeof(packet), 0)` to send it.

Receiving and printing the response:

```
unsigned char buffer[1024];
if ((recv(sockfd, buffer, len, 0)) == 0)
    {
        if (errno != 0)
        {
            exit(1);
        }
    }

    int i;
    for(i = 0; i<len; i++)
        printf("%x ", buffer[i]);
```

Am I right?

Comment: Have you tried this?

Comment: @EdHeal: Of course I've tried. But the thing is, t he response I'm getting from server is really strange. Also, I'm not sure if I can build packets like this: using simple chars and assign them hexes.

Comment: Do you really mean raw data packets? Or are you using TCP or UDP? Because your "packet" doesn't look like a valid packet for any network protocol I know since it contains no destination address.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: I use TCP sockets. It's just a websocket frame.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: So, how should I modify it?

Comment: If you're implementing WebSockets(WS), you don't need raw sockets: WS are based on TCP, just use normal TCP sockets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other than mishandling the return value from `recv`, your code looks okay.

```
if ((recv(sockfd, buffer, len, 0)) == 0)
    {
        if (errno != 0)
        {
            exit(1);
        }
    }
```

A zero return indicates normal close of the connection. There's no reason to check `errno` if it returns zero.

A return value of `-1` indicates an error. In that case, it does make sense to check `errno`.

A value greater than zero indicates that number of bytes have been received. Be aware that it is perfectly normal for `recv` to return fewer bytes than you asked it for. If you want to receive exactly some number of bytes, you must call `recv` in a loop.

TCP is a byte-stream protocol and has no idea where your "packets" (really, messages) begin and end.

Comment: But if I send the data to the echo server, and I know that it should respond with the exact data I sent it, maybe I should modify the `recv` to `recv(sockfd, buffer, 11, 0)`, where `11` stands for the exact number of bytes I want to receive? If it's not the right method, how the libraries do this?

Comment: @mirx Read my answer. If you get a return value of, say, 1, then call `recv` again to receive 10 more. TCP doesn't know those 11 bytes are a message and has no way to "glue" them together except by luck. The number you pass to `recv` is just the maximum number of bytes to return (the size of the buffer). It will return fewer if it has fewer at that moment.

Comment: Fine, I will implement `recv_count`.

Comment: *There's no reason to check errno if it returns zero.* There's not only no reason to check `errno` against zero if `recv()` returns zero, checking `errno` in that case is *wrong*.  If `recv()` returns zero, it leaves the value of `errno` unchanged, so `errno`'s contents are unrelated to the result of the `recv()` call and can be anything.

Answer (score 1):

Your code will not appear to be error-prone!

But a good practice would be:

```
const std::uint32_t BUFFER_SIZE = 11;

std::vector<std::uint8_t> buffer;
buffer.reserve(BUFFER_SIZE)

buffer = {0x81,0x8c.....};

send( sockfd,
      reinterpret_cast <const char*> ( buffer.data() ),
      static_cast      <int>         ( buffer.size() ),
      0
      );
```

Doing so, your code gets more optimized, and avoids possible leaks, using the **`std`** vectors.

May also benefit from taking a look at [**ZeroMQ**](http://zeromq.org/), as an example of a ready-made, high-performance asynchronous messaging library, aimed at use in distributed or concurrent applications.